# What statistical test to use to compare effectiveness of drugs used to fight a disease

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

So let's say that I want to collect some data on a sample of people who has the same type of disease.

One group will take a drug A

Another one will take drug B

Third type will take both of them.

I want to perform a statistical test to see whether taking both of the drugs simultaneously results in getting back to health quicker.

Can anyone tell me what test would I use and what hypothesis would I state? Assumptions that I would make?

I need to plan a research project (Without actually doing it) and I thought about doing something like this but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Why don't you look up an existing study and see what test(s) they used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need some value to measure for each patient that expresses
his/her progress toward recovery. Lower level of a liver enzyme, 
low count of bacterium or virus in blood, days for temperature return to normal, etc.
Call such a measured value $Y.$

**Model.** The standard design that best matches the description of your study is a
one-factor analysis of variance (ANOVA) with three levels of the factor,
A, B, AB. One hopes it would be ethical from a medical point of view to
assign, say $N = 60$ patients at random, so that there are $n = 20$ subjects
in each of $g = 3$ groups (with $N = ng$).

The model for such an ANOVA design is
$$Y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + e_{ij},$$

where $i = 1,2,3;\; j - 1, \dots, 10$ and $e_{ij} \stackrel{iid}{\sim}
\mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$

**Assumptions.** Assumptions of the model are that the subjects are randomly selected, data are normal,
and the population SD $\sigma$ is the same in each group.

**Hypotheses.** The null hypothesis is  $H_0: \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3$
and the alternative is $H_a: \alpha_i$ not all equal.

You can look up the ANOVA table, formulas, and F-test in a statistic text
or online. There are also help pages online for doing ANOVA computations in 
various kinds of statistical software.

**Power.** In planning such an experiment, you might try to do a preliminary power
computation. That requires guessing the numerical value of $\sigma,$
perhaps based on prior experience with recovery from this disease using
drugs A and B. Also, you would need to have an idea how much difference
in $Y$-values would be of interest. Then you could find out whether $n = 20$
subjects per group gives a realistic chance of detecting a difference of
the desired size if it is really present.

**Contrast.** Also you might want to look at a 'contrast' of the form $\frac{\alpha_A + \alpha_B}{2} - \alpha_{AB}.$ That focuses on the specific goal to
see whether the combination of A and B together gives better results
than one drug by itself. [A 'contrast' is a linear combination of 'effects'
$\alpha_i$ of the form $c_1\alpha_1 + c_2\alpha_2 + c_3\alpha_3,$ such
that $\sum_i c_i = 0.$ In my example, $c_1 = c_2 = .5$ and $c_3 = -1.$]

A text on basic experimental design will include information about power
computations and testing (pre-planned) contrasts. You can also find such
information online, but stick to pages from authoritative sources--NIST, class
notes at reputable universities, and Wikipedia pages that seem to be
in final form. (Any idiot can pose as an expert on experimental design,
and several do.)